# Algebraic theories and canonical algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am reading Bodo Pareigis-Categories and functors (Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. 39).

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an algebraic theory (in the sense of [Lawvere theories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory)).
A product-preserving functor $A:\mathcal{U}\longrightarrow Set$ is called an $\mathcal{U}$-algebra.

An $\mathcal{U}$-algebra $A$ is called canonical if $A(n)=A(1)\times\ldots\times A(1)$, where the right product is the set of $n$-tuples with elements of $A(1)$ and if $A(p_n^i)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_i$ for all $n$ and $i$, where $p_n^i:n\longrightarrow 1$ is the $i$th projection from $n=1\times\ldots\times 1$ to $1$ in $\mathcal{U}$.

I can't understand the difference between the notion of an $\mathcal{U}$-algebra and the notion of a canonical $\mathcal{U}$-algebra. I mean, by definition, every algebra is a product-preserving functor, so each of them should be already canonical. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read things correctly, "canonicity" is the requirement that $A(n)$ actually **is** the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $A(1)$, etc. This is not guaranteed to be the case, even though $A$ preserves products, because products are only defined *up to isomorphism*.

To elaborate: for any nonempty sets $X, Y$, there will be many (in fact, proper class many!) triples $(A, f, g)$ which satisfy the universal property of being a product of $X$ and $Y$; the special case where $A=X\times Y$ is the actual Cartesian product and $f, g$ are the actual projection maps is the "canonical" one, though, and this is what canonicity is demanding. (Although there are those who consider this sort of thing evil . . . http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence)